# Connection Pooling in GlassFish 4.1

Tags: java, web-services, connection-pooling

In an old web application I used a tomcat server. In order to configure the connection pool for the web application I modified the context.xml file of the application. I did not do anything to the server files. This way I was able to have different pools for different applications on the same server. I am now developing a new web application but this time using a glassfish 4.1 server. Based on the internet searches I performed it seems that I will have to modify the server files themselves in order to set up the server for connection pooling. Is there a way to modify a file within the web application only and have this file be read by the server, the same way that the context.xml file works for tomcat? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to modify any server files. You can create the connection pool from the Admin console which you can access at `http://localhost:4848`

Then navigate to Resources > JDBC> JDBC Connection Pools to create a new connection pool.

You can also test the connection using the Ping button.

To use the connection in the application you need to do a JNDI lookup as below

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("datasource jndi name");
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

**Update**
What you are looking for is application scoped resources. For resources to be specific to your application you need to create WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml file which will create resources when war is deployed and remove them when undeployed.

glassfish-resources.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource   Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-connection-pool name="java:app/appConnectionPool" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
   datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
    <property name="ServerName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="Port" value="3306" />
    <property name="DatabaseName" value="demojpa" />
    <property name="User" value="demojpa" />
    <property name="Password" value="password"/>
    <property name="Url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demojpa"/>
    <!-- property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/ not required -->
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/appDataSource" object-type="user" 
pool-name="java:app/appConnectionPool"/>
</resources>
```

Lookup the datasource using "java:app/jdbc/appDataSource" jndi name. Have created a blog post for this at [Glassfish application scoped resources](http://blog.techdynamic.me/glassfish/)

Comment: Yes but this is just a way to modify the server through the admin console. What I want is for the connection pool settings to be associated with the web application and not with the server.

Comment: ahh.. you can configure the resources in glassfish-resources.xml and package it along the war. That should create the specified resources when the war is deployed.